# Write and read files from SD card flutter

Tags: flutter, directory, storage, sd-card, android-external-storage

Is there any way to Read and write files from external SD Card with flutter ,like using

> getExternalStorageDirectory()

from path_provider package to access local storage(read,write,modify,create..)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [external_path](https://pub.dev/packages/external_path) package in pub.dev.

There is another way, which is directly listing all folders before folder named 0. There are mostly three folders in the very root: emulated, (the second and third one I don't remember now).If SD card is also inserted, there is a change in the first index with some id of SD card. But, trying to directly list them throws permission error, so you should use the package provided above.

About, writing (editing, deleting), it's really hard using flutter. By default, the contents are loaded in read-only mode.